# Adding additional pages to envelope created from a template

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to add extra pages to the middle of the document on envelope created and ready to send from a set template.

Use case:

1. Using DocuSign UI, **Template-Sample** saved with 4 pages, signing tab at the end of 4th page
2. Using API on code, envelope is created with the Template-Sample
3. Add 1 or more pages (with data contents) after 3rd page on template
4. Send for signing.

Comment: Please remember to upvote useful answers and to checkmark the one that best answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes. While the envelope is in the `Created` status (draft), it is no problem to change the envelope's contents.

Changing a specific document within the envelope is only supported by changing the entire document. That's possible, but the easier way is to have a series of separate documents in the envelope, and then only insert the new document.

Eg, if you still want the signing page at the end of all the pages, you'd have three documents:

1. The front matter document
2. The document that you're changing on the fly
3. The final document, including the signature page

Doing this sort of document manipulation usually involves the use of composite templates. Please ask additional questions if you'd like more help.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So then I would need 3 templates instead of the one I have Template-Sample is that right?

Comment: Thanks. So to clarify, i would need 3 templates for #1, #2 & #3 documents is that right? As per my understanding, I would need a 'server template' for each document added to composite template right

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not yet up to speed enough to give you a good answer about using a composite template. I suggest that you google for other stack overflow questions about composite templates (there are several), and try it out. Then ask a NEW question on stackoverflow if you have a different question